# How to check for spaces before <?php?

Tags: regex, laravel-4, phpstorm

I'm building APIs using Laravel, and for some reason, the response generated seems to add a new line before returning the response. An example of this issue is explained in [this link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/blank-first-line-in-response?page=1).

I suspect this is because there is an empty space or new line character before the opening tags in one of the PHP files. I was wondering what's the easiest way to find it? I use PHPStorm, and it has a regex search option. I am quite clueless as to how to use it to find the files though. Any ideas?

Comment: You can find it using :- `\s+<\?php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `\s+<\?php`. To remove the spaces, replace the matches with `<?php`.